# error: expected activation_4 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (14, 3, 150, 150)

Tags: numpy, keras, convolution

I'm trying to use my own dataset that consists of two categories. I do not understand how can solve this. How can I fix this? it seems like the model gets the shape of the image as input instead of the actual image.

```
print X_train.shape
print y_train.shape
print X_test.shape
print y_test.shape

(55, 3, 150, 150)
(55, 1)
(14, 3, 150, 150)
(14, 1)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

model = Sequential()
#model.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(3, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(3,150,150)))
#model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image: model.summary()]

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_4 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (14, 3, 150, 150)
```

Comment: What's the meaning of the 4 dimensions of 'xtrain'?

Comment: 55 = numbers of samples, 3 is number of channels and 150 is width and height

Comment: where is your `model.fit()` statement?

Comment: Thanks for your question. It turned out accidentally used x_train as label. That solved my error

Answer (score 3):

What you're passing to the `fit` method as `Y` has 4 dimensions: `(14,3,150,150)`.

You're probably passing X instead of Y. Your Y must have shape `(14,2)`, according to the output of the last layer.

But if your Y has shape `(14,1)`, you should be using `Dense(1)` instead of `Dense(2)` at the end.